# joining dotted line by interpolation in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, interpolation, image-segmentation

I have this image as shown below. **It is a binary mask**

[image]

I created this image using the below code. Basically I got the `x_idx`, `y_idx` for just those white pixels, and I know the actual image size, so I first create an empty array and filled those lines with the help of `x_idx` and `y_idx`

```
image = np.empty((x_shape, y_shape))

def line_to_img(linedf, image):
    
    x_idx = linedf.x
    y_idx = linedf.y

    for i,j in zip(x_idx, y_idx):
        image[i, j] = 1
            
    return image
```

as you can see all pixels are the same except 2 lines, one on the left and one in right.

As you can  see that the right line is not continuous and I want to make this line continuous by some interpolation method

I've tried to work on two different methods to achieve this, but no luck so far

**1st Method using `skimage`**

`new_image = skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes(old_image, 40, connectivity=2, in_place=False)`

Output: [image]

Interpretation of output: Same image without any interpolation

**2nd Method using `cv2`**

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
new_image = cv2.morphologyEx(old_image,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
```

Output: [image]

Interpretation of output: Line got removed for some reason

Please help me on how to achieve this task and interpolate the line in the image to get a continuous line

**EDIT (Use-Case):** Basically I got the `x_idx`, `y_idx` for just those white pixels, and I know the actual image size, so I first create an empty array and filled those lines with the help of `x_idx` and `y_idx` I don't have control of the data, this is what it is, now I want to join the line on the right size. Basically, I've to create segmentation labels, in which above the line is one label and below the line is one label, left side is fine, I can divide the image into two labels based on that line, while the middle portion will remain for class 1 i.e., Upper part, while I know for sure that right side is a single line, it's just that the data I got is degraded, so I want this interpolation to come into the picture

Comment: Is it maybe the case that you had the line you seek in an earlier step of your processing and you might have been able to preserve it better when extracting it... rather than trying to re-create it? Just wondering.

Comment: I can hardly see anything in these pictures. don't post thumbnails please, but source resolution images (unscaled).

Comment: @MarkSetchell No I don't have control of the data, this is what it is, now I want to join the line on the right size. Basically, I've to create segmentation labels, in which above the line is one label and below the line is one label, left side is fine, I can divide the image into two labels based on that line, while the middle portion will remain for class 1 i.e., Upper part, while i know for sure that right side line is a single line, it's just that the data i got is degraded, so i want this interpoation to come into picture

Edited the question

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Actually that's how the actual data is, the whole image has black pixels except those white pixels. Please look into the edited section of question, I've added more information

Comment: “Line got removed for some reason” — the reason being that you applied an opening and this is exactly what an opening does. You maybe intended to apply a closing, but that will not close the gaps in the line either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're just looking to connect the region gaps in data, the Bresenham algorithm (which many know as a common line-drawing algorithm) should perform well in this case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

**Pseudo Algorithm:**

1. Get all (x, y) coordinate pairs from the binary mask
2. Sort from left to right by X (this assumes you'll have a horizontal line, and if not, you may choose to sort by a different means for various segmentation masks)
3. Iterate over each coordinate pair and use Bresenham to connect them.

**Implementation:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def _bresenham(x0: int, y0: int, x1: int, y1: int):
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0

    xsign = 1 if dx > 0 else -1
    ysign = 1 if dy > 0 else -1

    dx = abs(dx)
    dy = abs(dy)

    if dx > dy:
        xx, xy, yx, yy = xsign, 0, 0, ysign
    else:
        dx, dy = dy, dx
        xx, xy, yx, yy = 0, ysign, xsign, 0

    D = 2 * dy - dx
    y = 0

    for x in range(dx + 1):
        yield x0 + x * xx + y * yx, y0 + x * xy + y * yy
        if D >= 0:
            y += 1
            D -= 2 * dx
        D += 2 * dy

# Read in image and convert to binary mask
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Test\\so1.png", 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Get xy coordinate list of points
pairs = []
points = np.nonzero(thresh)
points_row = points[0]
points_col = points[1]

for row, col in zip(points_row, points_col):
    pairs.append((col, row))

# Sort coordinates by X
coords_sorted = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[0])

# Apply bresenham algorithm
result_coords = []
for n in range(len(coords_sorted) - 1):
    for p in _bresenham(coords_sorted[n][0], coords_sorted[n][1], coords_sorted[n + 1][0], coords_sorted[n + 1][1]):
        result_coords.append(p)

# Update the binary mask with the connected lines
for x, y in result_coords:
    thresh[y][x] = 255

plt.imshow(thresh, 'gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

**Output Mask:**

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Thank You for the solution.

But how will the code change if I do not want to fill the gap b/w right and left line

I only want to fill the gap b/w right line and left line separately, and keep middle portion as zero

Comment: also what do you mean by "Sort from left to right by X (this assumes you'll have a horizontal line, and if not, you may choose to sort by a different means for various segmentation masks)"? in this case all the lines are going to be horizontal, but it might so happen that dip of that line could be more than 45 degrees

Comment: @QuamerNasim A line at 45 degrees should work fine. All that matters is "drawing order" in a sense. If you want to avoid filling the large gap in the center, you could check euclidean distance between points and only connect lines less than some threshold.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply.

Another case: What if in case we have now 2 lines, one below the already existing one which similar to first-line is having gaps, will this code work for interpolating both the lines?

Comment: @QuamerNasim Not out-of-the-box it wouldn't, since Bresenham is based on connecting lines from one point to the next. Two lines running horizontally parallel would be sorted with their X values accordingly, and you'd end up with a mess. That's where you'll have to get clever in how you group and sort coordinates. E.g. instead of simply sorting by X, you can sort by euclidean distance from one point to the next. Sorting by distance iteratively might solve all use-cases for you. Although, I'm not sure how many edge cases you have.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions, but there's 1 issue with present solution. Pls check link to see input image & output image I got from code.

it has matched different discontinuity, instead of matching rightmost point of left side line with leftmost point of right size line it has matched lefttmost point of left side line with rightmost point of right size line

Can you please help me fix this

Input: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cBcalxEUr0hD-EirkU5xp1lm61Mwv7sn/view?usp=sharing


Output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_qaQ-G1TZTWtShYDKXd167OerRdRVDO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @QuamerNasim I don't see any additional links at the moment, but if you provide one I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: i've added the links, please have a look

Comment: Hope you can see the links now

Comment: Ran your input image through my implementation and it seems to work fine:
https://pasteboard.co/KaTewEM.png From your output image it looks as though your values aren't sorted in the proper order. I'd even suspect you're sorting by Y instead of X in this case.

Comment: this is strange, cause I'm using the exact same code as yours, all i've removed is thresholding as it's not required cause I have an image whose values are binary, could that be a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Since you're skipping the thresholding step (as you already have the indices), I'm guessing this is what's throwing your solution off: `pairs.append((col, row))` Note that I'm storing the tuples as (x, y). You might have the tuples reversed as (row, column) e.g. (y, x). If this is the case, you can always modify this line `sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[0])` to `sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Got it, thank you, now it's working fine

Thanks again for your support!

Comment: Hi again, now once I've interpolated the line and filled the gaps, can you help me now extrapolating this line further to meet both the ends (right now it's not necessary that line starts from one end and ends at other end, as you can see in the figure, though it might so happen that some of image may have complete line from one end to other

Comment: @QuamerNasim Just append two additional points to the sorted pairs list. Get the first pair (x,y) and append (0, y) to the front of the list, then get the last pair and append (image_width - 1, y) to the end of the list. This will extrapolate to the edges of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach using the extreme points of contours.

**Advantage?**

This approach has a slight advantage. For every contour obtained, there are 4 extreme points; these are the topmost, bottommost, rightmost and leftmost points of a contour. We **only** iterate these 4 points for every contour. Unlike the approach using Bresenham algorithm which iterates through every non-zero point in the image.

**Flow:**

- Obtain binary image
- Perform morphological operations to join nearby dots
- Find contours
- Iterate through the extreme points found for each contour and draw a line between the closest among them.

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('image_path', 0)
img1 = cv2.imread(f, 1)

# binary image
th = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# morphological operations
k1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, k1)
k2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
erode = cv2.morphologyEx(dilate, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, k2)
```

[image]

```
# find contours
cnts1 = cv2.findContours(erode, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts1) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = cnts1[0]

# For each contour, find the closest distance between their extreme points and join them
for i in range(len(cnts)):
    min_dist = max(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])
    cl = []
    
    ci = cnts[i]
    ci_left = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    ci_right = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    ci_top = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    ci_bottom = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
    ci_list = [ci_bottom, ci_left, ci_right, ci_top]
    
    for j in range(i + 1, len(cnts)):
        cj = cnts[j]
        cj_left = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        cj_right = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        cj_top = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        cj_bottom = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        cj_list = [cj_bottom, cj_left, cj_right, cj_top]
        
        for pt1 in ci_list:
            for pt2 in cj_list:
                dist = int(np.linalg.norm(np.array(pt1) - np.array(pt2)))     #dist = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
                if dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist = dist             
                    cl = []
                    cl.append([pt1, pt2, min_dist])
    if len(cl) > 0:
        cv2.line(erode, cl[0][0], cl[0][1], 255, thickness = 2)
```

The final result:

[image]

I talked about extreme points, but where are they located? The following snippet shows that:

```
# visualize extreme points for each contour
for c in cnts:
    left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    right = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    bottom = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
    
    # Draw dots onto image
    #cv2.drawContours(img1, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
    cv2.circle(img1, left, 2, (0, 50, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(img1, right, 2, (0, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(img1, top, 2, (255, 50, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(img1, bottom, 2, (255, 255, 0), -1)
```

[image]

The extreme points shown above are obtained from contours of image `erode`.